# Yii2 rest api extra fields

Tags: php, rest, api, yii2

I have included a field from a related table using extraFields function into CallRates endpoint. When listing the records "rate_increase" is displayed as expected:

```
{
  ....
    "manually_updated": "no",
    "created": "2017-10-13 15:15:43",
    "rate_increase": "50.00"
},
```

However when viewing a record individually it is displayed as null every time. Has anyone got any ideas? I am stumped.

To grab the field I have done the following in controller modelFind():

```
$query = $model::find()
        ->leftJoin('reseller_config', 'reseller_rate.resellerref = reseller_config.resellerref')
        ->select('reseller_rate.*, reseller_config.rate_increase');
```

And then in the model to include the field:

```
public function fields()
{
    $fields = array_merge(parent::fields(), ['rate_increase']);

    return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement what you're trying to do, what I'do is:

1. Add in the model for reseller_rate table

   ```
   public function getResellerRate()
   {
     return $this->hasOne('reseller_config',['reseller_rate.resellerref'=> 'reseller_config.resellerref']);
   }
   ```
2. Then in fields function:

   `public function fields()
   {
       $fields = parent::fields();
       $fields['rate_increate'] = $this->resellerRate->seller_rate;
       return $fields;
   }`